# Setting default histtype in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-analysis

Is there a way to configure the default argument for `histtype` of matplotlib's `hist()` function? The default behavior is to make bar-chart type histograms, which I basically *never* want to look at, since it is horrible for comparing multiple distributions that have significant overlap.

In case it's somehow relevant, the default behavior I would like to attain is to have `histtype='step'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for prompting me to look at this, as I much prefer `'step'` style histograms too! I solved this problem by going into the matplotlib source code. I use anaconda, so it was located in `anaconda/lib/site-packages/python2.7/matplotlib`.

To change the histogram style I edited two of the files. Assuming that the current directory is `matplotlib/`, then open up `axes/_axes.py` and locate the `hist()` function there (it's on line 5690 on my machine, matplotlib version 1.5.1). You should see the `histtype` argument there. Change this to `'step'`.

Now open up `pyplot.py` and again locate the `hist()` function and make the same change to the `histtype` argument (line 2943 in version 1.5.1 and on my machine). There is a comment about not editing this function, but I only found this to be an issue when I didn't also edit `axes/_axes.py` as well.

This worked for me! Another alternative would be just to write a wrapper around `hist()` yourself that changes the default argument.

Comment: Thanks for looking into it. I have basically been using a wrapper function for hist; unfortunately hacking the source-code in-situ is not an option since I need my code to work in various environments that I don't control. But as you found it is hard-coded, I guess that answers my question. It would have been nice to be able to control this with matplotlibrc.